# Confused about addTarget pointer behavior for addTarget:action:forControlEvents:

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, uiview, uicontrol

I have a UIView subclass with a delegate property. In the init method, I set

```
self.delegate = nil.
```

The view also has a button, so in the init method, I also set the target of the button to be self.delegate, which is nil:

```
[myButton addTarget:self.delegate action:@selector(buttonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
```

In the UIViewController that sets up my UIView subclass, I call a method in the UIView that sets the UIView's self.delegate to the UIViewController. When I click the button, the change in target seems to be reflected.

I am wondering how this ends up working, as my understanding is that addTarget:action:forControlEvents takes an id as the target, and pointers should be pass by value in Obj-C. Thus, I am pretty confused about why the originally nil-valued pointer was updated after the addTarget method was already called.

Comment: Target, as you see by setting it to `self.delegate`, is a reference type and therefore behaves as one. I'm not sure what you mean by pass a pointer by value as a pointer is what we refer to as a reference. Making a pointer with a type is how we get our reference type and `id` (which is what target is) is an example of one.

Comment: My understanding is that pointers are memory addresses of the data object to which they reference. When you pass a pointer as a method argument, you are passing in the value of this memory address. However, this does not explain why changing the value of the pointer in the original UIView class should change the value of the pointer that was passed to the addTarget method. It seems these cases typically make use of a ** pointer to a pointer.

Comment: I see your point and indeed you're right. Looking at the documentation for that method, part of the definition for target `If this is nil, the responder chain is searched for an object willing to respond to the action message`. So this is probably happening because that view is the only subview that can respond to `buttonAction`

Comment: Thank you, this explains it.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do that is declaring a protocol for your view, which will delegate for button's tap action, i.e.

YourView.h

```
@class YourView;
@protocol YourViewDelegate
@optional
- (void)customView:(YourView *)view didSelectButton:(id)button;

@end

@interface YourView : UIView

//...
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <YourViewDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

YourView.m

```
@interface YourView()

@end

@implementation

- (id)init
{
   if (self = [super init]) {
      //...
      [self setup];
   }

   return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    //...
    // setup logic when this view created from storyboard
    [self setup];
}

- (void)setup
{
    [myButton addTarget:self 
                 action:@selector(buttonTapped:)     
       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(customVIew:didSelectButton)] {
       [self.delegate customView:self didSelectButton:sender];
    }
}
@end
```

Then, in your view controller implement YourViewDelegate category:

```
@interface YourViewController() 

//...
@end

@implementation

- (void)viewDidLoad
{ 
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //...
    self.yourView.delegate = self;
}

//...
- (void)customView:(YourView *)view didSelectButton:(id)button
{
    //do your stuff
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. It is very useful. Do you know why changing the value of self.delegate was also changing the value referenced by the addTarget method, even though the value of self.delegate was nil when I call the addTarget method?

Answer (score 0):

`Objective-C` uses `Dynamic binding`. Method to invoke is determined at runtime instead of at compile time. Which is why it is also referred to as late binding.

Reference link - 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/DynamicBinding.html

So what will be the delegate and which method is being called is defined at runtime.

Comment: Isn't `Dynamic binding` really just a fancy way of saying Objective-C does everything using pointers?